# How to find specific rows in csv document in python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is read into a csv document and find all values in the SN column > 20 and make a new file with only the rows with SN > 20.

I know that I need to do:

1. Read the original File
2. Open a new file
3. Iterate over rows of the original file

What I've been able to do is find the rows that have a value of SN > 20

```
import csv
import os

os.chdir("C:\Users\Robert\Documents\qwe")

with open("gdweights_feh_robert_cmr.csv",'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ',')
    zerovar = 0
    for row in reader:
        if zerovar==0:
            zerovar = zerovar + 1
        else:
            sn = row [11]
            zerovar = zerovar + 1
            x = float(sn)
            if x > 20:
                print x
```

So my question is how do I take the rows with SN > 20 and turn it into a new file?

Comment: instead of 'print x' output to a file handle.

Comment: Skip the header with `next(reader)` before the loop, to remove the `if-then` statement from the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the data in a list, then write the list to a file.

```
import csv
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Robert\Documents\qwe")

output_ary = []
with open("gdweights_feh_robert_cmr.csv",'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter= ',')
    zerovar = 0
    for row in reader:
        if zerovar==0:
            zerovar = zerovar + 1
        else:
            sn = row [11]
            zerovar = zerovar + 1
            x = float(sn)
            if x > 20:
                print x
                output_ary.append(row)

with open("output.csv",'w') as f2:
    for row in output_ary:
        for item in row:
            f2.write(item + ",")
```

Comment: It sounds like it should be `output_ary.append(row)`

Comment: This uses quite a bit more memory than is necessary; just print the appropriate lines to the output file as they are read, instead of storing them all in a list.

Comment: When I try doing this, I get a TypeError: expected a character buffer object. What does this mean?

Comment: my mistake, I fixed it, please try again.

Comment: Sorry for late response...It works, however, I get a problem where it doesn't load everything. And only loads the first row.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, the reading / looping through the rows is is quite complex. It could be cleaned up (and run faster in Python) with the following:

```
with open('gdweights_feh_robert_cmr.csv', 'rb') as f:
    output_ary = [row for row in f if float(row[11]) > 20]
```

Using list comprehension ([row for row if f]) is optimised in python, so it will preform more efficiently. AND... you avoid having to create the `reader` array, which will reduce the memory required, also very handy if the csv file is large.

You can then proceed to write out the outout_ary as suggested in the other answers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem with this is that you cannot convert a string to a float.

Comment: That's interesting, it is perfectly acceptable to cast a string as a float, e.g. `s = '3', y = float(s)`. You might be observe conflict if the string contains non-numerical characters e.g. `float('3a')` will result in a ValueError. If the string contains quote symbols, this will also occur