# Python -- how to update/change specific fields in text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have read and performed some operations on specific feild I need to update that feild or entire record.
By using split method I have splited and performed some operations.
Now I need to update the new amount value.
Could please help me to update

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried? Also, an example would help.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.
Data in file : Dhana,101,1000
2nd field is ID, based on ID I am trying to updating amount
By using split method I have splited and performed some operations.
Now I need to update the new amount value.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored as:

Dhana,101,1000
Other,102,1001

then you have a csv file and can use the operations from the csv module.

You say "I have read ..." and this implies you have already loaded the csv into your program, in which case you might as well write out your data from a-fresh rather than risking editing one field in a csv. [Here is the csv module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) - in particular read the "writer" and "dictwriter" functions.

If for some reason you have not yet read in the csv file and you need to scroll through it to find the value, [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891609/how-to-find-specific-rows-in-csv-document-in-python) has the explanation of how to do it - change the x > 20 test to a test for the id you are looking for.